# How to extract TabNet Embeddings?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, embedding

I am trying to implement the same method with this paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9658729

[image: Model Architecture]

I know how to get Bert Embeddings but I cannot find any method on how to get the TabNet Embedding from https://github.com/dreamquark-ai/tabnet

Do I need to go inside the TabNet and extract the embedding through the layers?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Tabnet's Embedding with something like this:

```
from pytorch_tabnet.tab_network import EmbeddingGenerator
    embedding_generator = EmbeddingGenerator(input_dim=input_dim, cat_dims=cat_dims, cat_idxs=cat_index, cat_emb_dim=1)
    embeddings = embedding_generator(tensor_data)
```

The object `embeddings` will then have the Tabnet embeddings.

Here is the documentation for this: https://dreamquark-ai.github.io/tabnet/generated_docs/pytorch_tabnet.html#pytorch_tabnet.tab_network.EmbeddingGenerator

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am having trouble understanding cat_dims and cat_idxs. How do I obtain the value for that?

Comment: The cat_dims is the number of modalities for each categorical features (the number of options the categorical value can have) and cat_idxs is the positional index for each categorical features in inputs. All this is easily found in the documentation linked above. Hope that helps!

Comment: Could you mark this answer as the best?